# A regular expression for splitting symbols of a BNF grammar

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, bnf

I need to iterate over symbols of production rules of form:

e.g: 
Input

```
<relational operator> ::= = | <> | < | <= | >= | > | in
<next constant definition> ::= <empty> | <next constant definition> ; <constant definition>
```

so I was in need to derive a regular expression to split the text. Here's what I have so far

```
(?:\s|^|\s<|^<)(?:.*?)(?:\s|$|\s>|>$)
```

the problem is `re.findall()` doesn't produce my desired output

Expected output is:

```
[<relational operator>, ::=, =, |, <>, |, <, |, <=, |, >=, |, >, |, in]
[<next constant definition>, ::=, <empty>, |, <next constant definition>, ;, <constant definition>]
```

Comment: Sure, what have you tried so far? Where's your code?

Comment: @Ngenator Well, I've tried a lot of things, the latest one is: (?:\s|^|\s<|^<)(.*?)(?:\s|$|\s>|>$) As I'm editing the code I'm still not sure if this even works, but the problem is, re.findall() neither produces all possible answers nor my desired output

Comment: Why not use an implementation of "yet another compiler compiler", like http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Comment: @Ngenator I've been assigned to implement an LR(1) parser from scratch for Pascal.

Comment: It's probably better to simply iterate through the string and check for `<` `>` and spaces to help parse. Regular expressions are not very efficient.

Comment: @mbomb007 I've already implemented it in the way you suggest, but it introduces a lot of problems in the later stages.

Comment: First thing, you might want a non-capturing group for the middle group, for consistency.

Comment: It's easier to answer questions that contains a definition (specification) of what is expected and not only a example. Until you describe the syntax you want to parse, it will be hard to analyse the corner cases ... which ultimately make the difference between a correct program and a buggy one !

Comment: @SergeBallesta Elements inside <> are non-terminals of the grammar and should be treated as a whole. other elements are terminals and are separated by space between them. the question is how to parse the line so that we elicit all of the elements. that's all

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use `(?:[\S]+)`? You should be able to assume that what you parse is valid BNF syntax. And every element is separated by a space. There shouldn't be spaces between each `<` and `>`, since hyphens are normally used instead.

Comment: @mbomb007 yes, that's right, thanks but didn't make much difference. the current output that I get is
['<next ', ' definition> ', ' <empty> ', ' <next ', ' definition> ', ' <constant ']

Comment: What defines a terminating character?

Comment: @mbomb007 for non-terminals it is '>' and for terminals it is either $ (end-of-line) or space.

Comment: but the problem is it might be confused with > which can both play the role of a terminal and end of a non-terminal. for example we might have a rule(actually we have) like <A B> ::= <A> <B> | > | <

Comment: @AhmadSiavosh that's the reason why I say you must first clearly give the specs of your parser, control they are coherent, and analyse the possible ambiguities. Only then you will know if you can use one regexp for the whole line that directly gives you classified elements, or if it just give you intermediate elements that you still have to parse again.

Comment: @SergeBallesta It seems there is no other way but using two regular expressions. although it introduces another problem, and it is how to maintain order of elements while merging the two intermediate answers. one for terminals and one for non-terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using something simple like  `<\w+(?:\s+\w+)*>|\S+`

```
   < \w+ 
   (?: \s+ \w+ )*
   >
|  
   \S+
```